# How to add arrows to Visio Activity Diagram Connector?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

How do you add arrows to the connectors in a Visio Activity Diagram?

As per the picture, explicitly setting an arrow doesn't work. Unlike the "UML" Use Case Diagram, the Activity Diagram doesn't appear to have it's own custom connectors.

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. To me all the shapes are connecting with arrows at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Under Stencils -> More Shapes -> Software and Database -> ...

Select UML Use Case, and UML Sequence in order to access those directional connectors. I was having the same issue and this is how I was able to correct it.

Comment: I love that three years later, I come back to my own post and use your solution again!

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, but to help other people out there I'm posting what I found.

If you choose Activity Diagram template to create the file, you'll have the arrows by default, but you probably created an empty diagram without choosing a template. In this case, you can select the connector, right click on it and choose Format Shape. A panel will appear on the right side (probably) of your screen, then you can choose the "End arrow type" as shown in the picture bellow.

[image: Format Shape]

Comment: This doesn't work - the Arrow Type selection remains "None" after I pick an arrow type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is hover over the action component or the component which you would like to connect from and small arrow heads will appear on the four sides of the component. Use that to create the next component and the arrow will appear automatically.